# How should I design a monochromatic flag

Tags: website-design, logo, symbolism, monochrome

I am in the process of making a web page and I have a "thanks to" section which shows the logotypes of different organizations. The customer wants these logos to be monochromatic; as in white background and dark gray logos (not shaded). However, one of these organizations is an embassy and they use the national flag as their logo.
The flag in question is Taiwan's, but It seems that we are going to need to incorporate some other flags as well.
So, how would you design a monochromatic flag in this case?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: just outline it: http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/72300/72359/72359_tw_flag_bw_sm.gif

Comment: First: the organisations might well have black and white versions of their logos to give you. But you could just run the logo into grayscale? I think that would look better than an outline. You will have other logos there, and a simple hairline logo will probably drown in the company of other, stronger logos.

Comment: This sort of thing would work for Taiwan, the UK, the USA, Cyprus, and a couple of other countries with distinctive flags, but not for the many many countries which use tricolours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply alter the coloring using your background grey to fill the dark area of the flag:

[image]

Comment: This one looks great along with the rest of the logos. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use their national symbol? I think it looks better than trying to force the flag.

[image]